# How do I group by month when when calculating duration in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Using R, I'm calculating the duration of a fault (in days) as below:

```
CreatedDate <-  as.Date( "2019-01-15")

ClosedDate <- as.Date("2019-08-20")

Fault_Days <- difftime(ClosedDate,CreatedDate, units = "days")
```

I get the output below:

> Fault_days [1] Time difference of 217 days

How can I get the output below instead?

> Fault_days
>
> Month Days
>
> January 16
>
> February 28
>
> March 31
>
> April 30 and so on until August with 20 fault days

I have tried using group_by but error message says it wont work with class "difftime"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: question not clear, do you want a sequence of dates between "2019-01-15" and "2019-08-20"  by 20 days period ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with 'lubridate' package using the following code:

```
last_day <- function(date) {
  ceiling_date(date, "month") - days(1)
}


first_day <- function(date) {
  ceiling_date(date, "month")
}

Date <- CreatedDate
firstDate <- Date

while (Date < ClosedDate)
{ 
lastDate<-last_day(Date)
if (lastDate >=ClosedDate)
{
  lastDate= ClosedDate
}
  x<-difftime(lastDate,firstDate, units = "days")
  print(paste(months(Date),x))
  Date<- first_day(Date)
  firstDate<-lastDate
}
```

This should give following output:

```
[1] "January 16"
[1] "February 28"
[1] "March 31"
[1] "April 30"
[1] "May 31"
[1] "June 30"
[1] "July 31"
[1] "August 20"
```

You can also save it in a dataframe.

Comment: The question appeared like a riddle and you solved it. Great!

Answer (score 1):

I would use lubridate to help with this problem.

```
library(lubridate)

CreatedDate <-  as.Date( '2019-01-15')
ClosedDate <- as.Date('2019-08-20')

CreatedDate <-  as.Date( '2019-01-15')
ClosedDate <- as.Date('2019-08-20')

#We can convert the month numbers to names
month_map <- data.frame(month_num = 1:12, month_name = c("Jan","Feb","Mar",
                                                     "Apr","May","Jun",
                                                     "Jul","Aug","Sep",
                                                     "Oct","Nov","Dec"))
#generate a df of dates

df <- data.frame(falut_date = seq(ymd(CreatedDate),ymd(ClosedDate), by = '1 day'))

#extracting the month number
df$month <-  month(df$falut_date)
df %>% 
inner_join(month_map, by = c('month'= 'month_num'))%>%
count(month_name)
```